# After moving my Wordpress to a new server with PHP 8.2, I can no longer edit images in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, php-8.2

I searched for this question and could not find a similar one for my problem.  So, here goes...

I moved to a new EC2 server (Linux 2) and have installed everything I thought was needed.  However, now when I login to the back end of my Wordpress sites, I am no longer able to "edit" (crop, resize, etc.) images - like a featured image. No image is shown when I click "Edit Image". I have tried turning off all plugins... no change.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for Programming Q&A. You might receive a better response at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein.  You're absolutely right.  I asked there and got an immediate, correct answer.  I'll close this.  Thanks!

Comment: Great! Feel free to Delete the question here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JohnRotenstein, I copied this question to the Wordpress exchange, and it was immediately, and correctly, answered.  The problem was the GD was not installed for PHP.  I installed it, and voila!

Thanks everyone!